# Magento 2.0 Unknown module(s): error when enabling custom module from command line

Tags: magento-2.0

I've read Magento's DevDocs and Googled this problem but the usual missing `registration.php` answer doesn't apply here.
I'm on the released CE 2.0.0 version and I'm simply trying to enable my first minimum test module in `magento/vendor/` but

```
bin/magento module:enable -c Tchsl_Test
```

results in:

> Unknown module(s): 'Tchsl_Test'

I am basing this on the naming conventions and file positions of modules in `vendor/magento/`

In `vendor/tchsl/module-test/etc/module.xml` I have

```
<config xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Tchsl_Test" />
</config>
```

In `vendor/tchsl/module-test/registration.php` I have

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Tchsl_Test',
    __DIR__
);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem and after some tinkering, discovered that our Modules *actually* belong under `app/code/Tchsl/Test/`. Move your module files there, and running the shell command `module:status` should show your disabled module.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put your module under `app/code/`. In `app/code/` Magento2 will search and find your module's `registration.php`. In Composer's `vendor/` dir it doesn't do that, so we need to trick Composer into loading your module's `registration.php`.

If you'd check any Magento2 module's `composer.json` in `vendor/magento/module-*`, you'll see an `"autoload"` section which references the `registration.php` file. So Composer will autoload your module's `registration.php` which will *"tell"* Magento2 where your module is located.

This is a fragment from the [Magento Checkout](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/composer.json) module's `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Checkout\\": ""
    }
}
```

So if you have your module in a separate repository and loaded via composer, then that is the way to go. If you do not have it in a separate repository, then your module does not belong on `vendor/` but in `app/code/`.

---

*See also [this Magento Stack Exchange post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/87354/3326).*